# Routing in Symfony2

Tags: php, routes, symfony

How to setup default routing in Symfony2?

In Symfony1 it looked something like this:

```
homepage:
  url:   /
  param: { module: default, action: index }

default_symfony:
  url:   /symfony/:action/...
  param: { module: default }

default_index:
  url:   /:module
  param: { action: index }

default:
  url:   /:module/:action/...
```

Answer (score 28):

I was looking through the cookbook for an answer to this, and think I've found it [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html).  By default, all route parameters have a hidden requirement that they match any character *except* the / character ([^/]+), but this behaviour can be overridden with the requirements keyword, by forcing it to match *any* character.

The following should create a default route that catches all others - and as such, should come last in your routing config, as any following routes will *never* match.  To ensure it matches "/" as well, a default value for the url parameter is included.

```
default_route:
    pattern: /{url}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Default:index, url: "index" }
    requirements:
        url: ".+"
```

Comment: Worked, cheers but just to enhance: "Default" is the classname of your controller (first letter capitalized without the "Controller" part).

Comment: There is a problem with the code presented in this answer, it needs a route name. Currently `pattern:` is assumed to be the route name and `pattern:`, `defaults:` and `requirements:` need to indented at the same level.

Comment: Thanks, that was probably a rush copy/paste job from my routes file!

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it's possible with the standard routing component.
Take a look to this bundle, it might help :
https://github.com/hidenorigoto/DefaultRouteBundle

Comment: Another way is to do it with annotations http://bundles.symfony-reloaded.org/frameworkextrabundle/#annotations-for-controllers Still no default route.

Comment: No, it's possible. See the answer below.

Answer (score 8):

// Symfony2 PR10

in routing.yml:

```
default:
    pattern:  /{_controller}
```

It enables you to use this kind of urls: http://localhost/MySuperBundle:MyController:myview

Answer (score 4):

Symfony2 standard routing component does not support it, but this bundle fills the gap Symfony1 left:

https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswDefaultRoutingBundle

It does what you expect. You can default route a bundle using this syntax:

```
FosUserBundle:
  resource: "@FosUserBundle"
  prefix:   /
  type:     default
```

It scans your bundle and automatically adds routes to your router table that you can debug by executing:

```
app/console router:debug
```

Example of automatically added default routes:

```
[router] Current routes
Name                          Method Pattern
fos_user.user.login_check     ANY    /user/login_check.{_format}
fos_user.user.logout          ANY    /user/logout.{_format}
fos_user.user.login           ANY    /user/login.{_format}
...
```

You see that it also supports the automatic "format" selection by using a file extension (html, json or xml).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example: http://docs.symfony-reloaded.org/master/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html#routing

A route definition has only one mandatory parameter `pattern` and three optionals parameters `defaults`, `requirements` and `options`.

Here's a route from my own project:

```
video:
    pattern:  /watch/{id}/{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: SiteBundle:Video:watch }
    requirements: { id: "\d+", slug: "[\w-]+"
```

Comment: I know how to add parameters to my route. But I want to match controller and action to have routes like /controller/action/params...

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use @Route annotation directly in a controller file. see https://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/annotations/routing.rst

As for the default routes, I think Symfony2 encourages explicit route mapping.

Comment: I think what's odd, is that if you generate your bundle using the console tools, it creates a default controller with routing defined via annotations. But the official book makes no mention of routing via annotations - there's no mention in the book. If this is the default setup, I would think it should be pointed out and documentation (or links to it) provided.

Answer (score 2):

Create a default route is not a good way of programming. Why? Because for this reason was implemented Exception.
Symfony2 is built just to do right things in the right way.

If you want to redirect all "not found" routes you should use exception, like NotFound404 or something similar. You can even customise this page at your own.

One route is for one purpose. Always. Other think is bad.

Comment: BASTA''s comment: "@Marc Morera Merino: consider this use case - a blog with default view, single post view, guestbook, guestbook entry form etc. For the default view, I don't want the URL to be of the form `http://example.com/blog/slug`, but simply `http://example.com/slug`. This will be the default view of the site, and certainly nothing that can be conceived as 'exception'".

Comment: Also, it is completely reasonable to want to have your JS handle the routing and dynamically load the application view, in this case all routes would serve a base layout and your JS router would determine the URL and render the view. This calls for a catch all route

Comment: Marc, I guess you haven't heard about SEO, changing routes is sometimes necessary when restructuring a site and a catch-all may be needed to be able to give a correct redirect (301 Status)

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own bundle that handled all requests and used URL parameters to construct a string to pass to the controller's forward method.  But that's pretty crappy, I'd go with well defined routes, it keeps your URLs cleaner, and decouples the URL and controller names.  If you rename a bundle or something, do you then have to refactor your URLs?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a "catch all", your best bet would be to hook on the `KernelEvents::EXCEPTION` event.  This event gets triggered whenever an Exception falls through to the `HttpKernel`, this includes the `NotFoundHttpException` thrown when the router cannot resolve a route to a Controller.

The effect would be similar to Symfony's stylized 404 page that gets rendered when you send the request through app_dev.php.  Instead of returning a 404, you perform whatever logic you're looking to.

Answer (score 0):

It depends... Some of mine look like this:

```
api_email:
resource: "@MApiBundle/Resources/config/routing_email.yml"
prefix: /
```

and some look like

```
api_images:
path:     /images/{listingId}/{width}/{fileName}
defaults: { _controller: ApiBundle:Image:view, listingId: null, width: null, fileName: null }
methods:  [GET]
requirements:
    fileName: .+
```