# Symfony2, Backbone and Pushstate

Tags: symfony, backbone.js, pushstate

I use symfony2 routing.yml for call main page:

```
web_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: SWebBundle:Default:index }
```

In this page i call Require, Backbone, use PushState, all ok, but, if one user go to, for example:

example.com **/categories/animals**

And copy this url and access directly, Symfony2 return 404

I use too patterns '/config/...' and '/api/...' for a lot of calls, and login/login_check

Well, i would like if exist any parameter 'default' for all calls where not appear in the routing, or to exclude config and api, because we controller 404 from backbone.js.

thanks ^^

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution for Symfony 2.3.2:

**routing.xml**

```
<routes>
    <route id="MyBundle.Default.index" path="/app">
        <default key="_controller">MyBundle:Default:index</default>
    </route>
    <route id="MyBundle.Default.index2" path="/app/{url}">
        <default key="_controller">MyBundle:Default:index</default>
        <requirement key="url">.+</requirement>
    </route>
</routes>
```

**Controller:**

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Here the reason https://stackoverflow.com/a/7892022 why I use:

```
<requirement key="url">.+</requirement>
```